# FreePBX call macros before any dial

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

Last FreePBX. I want run macros before any "Dial". How can make this? What`s context I must use?

I try use "macro-dial-one-custom", but freepbx dont call them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need write module to apply hooks in dialplan.

Some *-custom not work anymore.

Comment: Thx.But I used *-override file and replace dial* context and macro.